# Can't delete asset subfolder

Tags: assets

I just created a subfolder to test how it works but now can't delete it. If I select it and then click the "options wheel" in the bottom, the delete button is disabled.

Is there another way to delete a subfolder?

Craft Solo 4.4.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete a subfolder by navigating to it in CP > Assets > Subfolder and then clicking the triangle icon to the right of the subfolder in the breadcrumbs, which will give you a menu where there's a delete option.

[image]

It's not the easiest menu to find, especially when you're familiar with the 'cog' menu in the footer which allows you to delete every other type of content.

Comment: I agree - this is counter intuitive to the patterns the rest of the UI establishes. This is absolutely a recommendation that can be made on the Craft CMS github (if interested). Stack Exchange is community moderated, but devs do see the github posts.

https://github.com/craftcms/cms